# Packaging error: java.lang.RuntimeException: yu: unknown tag byte: 12

Tags: java, aide-ide, aide

So I'm currently trying to code a 1.16.4 Spigot plugin for minecraft in AIDE since my pc is broken and I have gotten no errors so far but once I run the program I get the build error:

```
packaging error java.lang.runtimeexception: yu: unknown tag byte: 12
```

I am not familiar with AIDE so I do not know if it something with the spigot jar or what but I am using `spigot-api-1.16.4-R0.1-20201203.083325-28-shaded.jar`

Answer (score 1):

IT happens because of some library if you implement in your project while using Aide.

Aide has problems with most of the libraries.

Try using another code editor or another library instead.

Something similar happened to me :

[How to fix packaging error in Aide (mobile IDE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65828711/how-to-fix-packaging-error-in-aide-mobile-ide?noredirect=1#comment116405189_65828711)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

You cannot use libraries, which need an higher target SDK version as your app, search a version of the library, which is compatible with your app.

I had the same problem today