# How to fix packaging error in Aide (mobile IDE)?

Tags: java, android, aide

I am creating android application using Aide (mobile ide).
My project has no errors but when I run the app, during building APK it displays an error dialog with message :

**'Packaging error: com.blankj.utilcode.util.ReflectUtil sSReflectException: java.lang.refle ct.InvocationTargetException
'**.

This has happened when I added these two libraries in my project:

**Dexter library** **:** *to handle runtime permission in android*

**KingsMentor library :** *to scan barcode or QR code*

Please help me how do I fix it?

Comment: Please add more details: error codes, error messages, etc.

Comment: @p-syche I have edited you can check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I know where the actual bug is.

If the same happens to you then kindly note that it is due to the 3rd party library that you are using in your project.

So the solution is to remove that library from your project and try another one , moreover try to code from scratch for that task if possible instead of using such libraries.

It happens because those libraries use another library or libraries.

Hope it helps you.

Happy coding :)